# How to fix "no valid OpenPGP data found" after piping gpg with "--status-id 1" to a file

Tags: gnupg

I have a script that uses gpg to encrypt a file and upload it to Google Drive:

```
cat backup.tar.gz \
  | gpg --symmetric --batch --status-fd 1 --with-colons --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase ${5} \
  | gdrive upload - backup.tar.gz.gpg
```

When trying to decrypt backup.tar.gz.gpg:

```
gpg backup.tar.gz.gpg
```

I get this error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
```

I think the problem is in using `--status-fd 1`.

Can anybody advice how to decrypt this existing file?

Comment: Why are you using cat for encryption? gpg has the option --encrypt-file ...

Comment: I'm using something like `mysqldump | gzip | gpg ...` in reality. I put `cat | gpg ...` here to simplify things, as I suppose it is irrelevant where the input is piped from.